# social networking site integration with asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, social-networking

I am integrating social networking sites likes Facebook,twitter and Google plus in my asp.net application.i was sending emails to my customers based on some data,in that mail i am using social media dashboard(like Facebook,twitter,LinkedIn,Gmail).

If my customer shares that information with his or her friends using any of these social networking websites i will give some discount to that customers. how could i know that my customer shared that information using these websites?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can via email in this way as you'll have no way to pick up in the users session and track the sharing. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you'd need to direct them to a page on your site, manually code the sharing process and catch the response in the callback. With this response you can then save the data and offer them a discount code or something.